# Find all $n$ for which such a set of coins exists

Tags: number-theory

> There is a set of $ n$ coins with distinct integer weights $ w_1, w_2, \ldots , w_n$. It is known that if any coin with weight $ w_k$, where $ 1 \leq k \leq n$, is removed from the set, the remaining coins can be split into two groups of the same weight. (The number of coins in the two groups can be different.) Find all $ n$ for which such a set of coins exists.

I am trying to prove that $n$ is an odd number, but I think I might've made a mistake.

**Lemma 1:** The number of weights $n$ must be an odd number.

If any coin is removed the remaining sets sum must be a multiple of $2$. Thus, $$w_2+w_3+\cdots+w_n \equiv 0 \mod 2,$$ $$w_1+w_3+\cdots+w_n \equiv 0 \mod 2$$ $$\vdots$$ $$w_1+w_2+\cdots+w_{n-1} \equiv 0 \mod 2.$$ Summing these up we get $(n-1)(w_1+w_2+\cdots+w_n) \equiv 0 \mod 2$. Thus, we have two cases: $n \equiv 0 \mod 2$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n w_i \equiv 0 \mod 2$ and $n \equiv 1 \mod 2$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n w_i \equiv 1,0 \mod 2$. In the first case, $w_i \equiv 0 \mod 2, \forall i = 1,\ldots,n$. This is impossible as by taking away one number we are left with an odd number of even numbers, which must be partitioned as an odd number of even numbers equals an even number of even numbers.

The last sentence is false, but I know that $n$ must be an odd number so what did I do wrong?